# Public access for REST API via Sites

Tags: rest-api, force.com-sites

I configured salesforce site(Build -> Site and created site to have public acess), then I add read/edit permission for account/contact for pulic/guest user and run GET request like:
http://ao-dev-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/

but I amd getting the response like

```
<Errors>
<script id="tinyhippos-injected"/>
<Error>
<errorCode>UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT</errorCode>
<message>HTTPS Required</message>
</Error>
</Errors>
```

Is it possible to have puclic REST API access via salesforcde public Sites?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

just add https instead of http `https:`//ao-dev-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/
Thanks Nagarjuna

Comment: I am having in this case:<Errors><Error><errorCode>INVALID_SESSION_ID</errorCode><message>Authorization required</message></Error></Errors>

Comment: Did you add the apex class for the rest API to the avaialble classes for the Sites profile? For non-authenticated REST, it needs to be added to the apex classes for the Sites Profile